# How to demonstrate excel mouse movement?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, mousemove

I'm trying make an application with .net and I can make basic things like open or edit excel files but I want to make copy-paste and show mouse movement in this copy-paste, mouse will go to select cells and copy. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: This screams "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)". Are you sure you want to cater for all display/window sizes, multi-monitor scenarios, being able to detect the scroll position in the Excel file and point the mouse at a particular cell? Or do you actually just want to programmatically read some given cells from an Excel file? As for your question, there is no such thing as "Excel mouse movement", Windows moves the mouse pointer. You can do that using platform invoking the `SetCursorPos(x, y)` API, but again, to determine the X and Y is actually the hard part here.

Comment: Yes, it's looking troubled, actually I need to paste something to excel file  and make a click on excel and I need to see moves but as you say XY can be problem, I have to try. Thanks for helping.